# Git commits reset unknown to my name

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

I changed my desktop(old to new) and forgot to add gitconfig file with username and email.

I commit and pushed lot of stuff on github from the last 1 month but didn't noticed my name was unknown.

Is there anyway i can reset that commits username from unknown to mine.

I already added config now but my previous major  contribution is unkown :-(.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a single command for you but you can use the [`filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) command to rewrite the commit information. There are some additional details [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). Then do a push with `--force` again and, assuming no one else has pulled from the repository, you're good to go.

Comment: we have a team of four people who are working on it my contribution is unknown :-( so i guess it will affect the working of others ?

Comment: Yes. They will see that the history has changed and will possibly get merge issues.

Comment: So what should i do ? just leave my work as unknown ?

Comment: The decision is yours. Either leave it that way (which is not what I would do) or notify your teammates and force push.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will talk to my mates.